# Reduce Meteor app initial load time

Tags: angularjs, meteor

As we've been developing our [meteor](http://www.meteor.com) (with angular) application, we've noticed that the load initial load times (no cache) are very slow: ~10 seconds. The main culprit seems to be the modules.js file, which holds all our node_modules, as it's around 2MB now.

We're importing modules in only the needed files, but they're still all being loaded at the start since we have to import those files in our main.js file so that angular can see the controller in the file.

I'm following the project structure outlined here: https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

Is there something obvious we've missed? Any tips on how to reduce that load time.

Comment: Analyze with `bundle-visualizer` and adopt dynamic imports. See [this blogpost](https://blog.meteor.com/putting-your-app-on-a-diet-with-meteor-1-5s-bundle-visualizer-6845b685a119).

Answer (score 2):

Publications can also slow down the initial load process. By default, Meteor projects include the [autopublish package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/autopublish), which publishes everything—that means it copies everything in the database to the client. If you have accrued a lot of data and autopublish is in effect, then your load time will suffer.